# How to set type of a property in Typescript as a combination of two ENUMs?

Tags: typescript

I have one enum:

```js
enum EAlphabet = {
    A = 'A',
    B = 'B',
    C = 'C',
    D = 'D',
    E = 'E',
    F = 'F',
    G = 'G',
    H = 'H',
    I = 'I',
    J = 'J',
    K = 'K',
    L = 'L',
    M = 'M',
    N = 'N',
    O = 'O',
    P = 'P',
    Q = 'Q',
    R = 'R',
    S = 'S',
    T = 'T',
    U = 'U',
    V = 'V',
    W = 'W',
    X = 'X',
    Y = 'Y',
    Z = 'Z'
}
```

I have an interface I want to give the property of it the type that defines the following: that it can be either 'A', 'X', 'D', or it can be 'AA', 'JB', 'ZE', or it can be 'ABC', 'ZJE'.

I'm not sure how to define it, but it would be something like this?

```js
interface foo {
    bar: EAlphabet + EAlphabet? + EAlphabet? /* What to do here? */
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all in such situation I would prefer using literal unions instead of Enum, it would be just handy to use it. Unfortunately you cannot do string concatenation on the type level, but you can change the representation into [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple), and get needed type safety.

So my solution contains exactly literal union, but the difference between using that with enum is really small.

```
type EAlphabet = 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D'; // literal union instead of enum

interface Foo {
    bar: [EAlphabet] | [EAlphabet, EAlphabet] | [EAlphabet,EAlphabet,EAlphabet],
    toString: () => string
}

const makeFoo = (chars: Foo['bar']): Foo => ({
    bar: chars,
    toString: function () {
        return this.bar.join('');
    }
});

const example = makeFoo(['A', 'B']); // only max three allowed, works
console.log(example.toString()) // outputs AB

const example2 = makeFoo(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']); // error wrong size
const example3 = makeFoo(['A', '*', 'C']); // error wrong sign
```

Main point of the solution is `[EAlphabet] | [EAlphabet, EAlphabet] | [EAlphabet,EAlphabet,EAlphabet]` we define that the type is or tuple with 1 or 2 or 3 elements, nothing more is allowed. BTW if any size is allowed then the type should be just `EAlphabet[]`.

Also importantly we can create value constructor - `makeFoo` which creates a valid type value, and as you can see I have added handy function `toString` which allows us to get back the string representation. So even though we use tuples under the hood, in any moment we can transform that into `string`.

---

Implementation of that with enum will be the same, the only difference is that we need to pass enum values instead of plain literals:

```
const example = makeFoo([EAlphabet.A, EAlphabet.B]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats not how enums work and probably not the best way to achieve this. You might need to define it as string and do your own regex check to see if it has 2-3 characters etc.

You COULD (but you probably shouldnt) do something like this tho.

```
// Array of EAlphabet with 2-3 Elements
export interface foo {
  [0]: EAlphabet;
  [1]: EAlphabet;
  [2]?: EAlphabet;
}

let a: foo;
a = [EAlphabet.A, EAlphabet.X, EAlphabet.D];
```

Keep in mind that

```
a = ['A', 'B']
```

still wont work this way.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the simplest type for your case could be a union of string literal types to discriminate the values:

```
type EAlphabetStringLit = 'A' | 'X' | 'D' | 'AA' | 'JB' | 'ZE' | 'ABC' | 'ZJE'
```

With above type there is no need to concatenate multiple enum value types to support  types akin to `'ABC'`. If you use enums to preserve [nominal typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html), e.g. to ensure that type `"A"` is different from `EAlphabet.A`, the next simple alternative is  to combine the elemental enum values:

```
enum EAlphabetNarrow {
    A, X, D, AA, JB, ZE, ABC, ZJE
}

const k = EAlphabetNarrow[EAlphabetNarrow.A] // "A"
```

In case of nominal typing, I also like [branded primitives](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal) for their simplicity:

```
type BrandedString<T extends string> = T & { __brand__: symbol }

function brandedStringOf<T extends string>(s: T): BrandedString<T> {
    return s as BrandedString<T>
}

type EAlphabetBrand = BrandedString<'A'> | BrandedString<'X'> | BrandedString<'D'> | BrandedString<'AA'>
    | BrandedString<'JB'> | BrandedString<'ZE'> | BrandedString<'ABC'> | BrandedString<'ZJE'>

const t1: EAlphabetBrand = "A" // error; "A" not assignable to BrandedString<"A">
const t2: EAlphabetBrand = brandedStringOf("A") // works, branded primitives are typed with assertion
const t3: EAlphabetBrand = brandedStringOf("ABC") // works, like above
```

And if you really need the element types `"A"`, `"B"`, etc. together with their concatenated forms `"ABC"`, etc., [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) may be used, as TS does not have computed string types yet:

```
type EAlphabetValues = EAlphabet.A | EAlphabet.X | EAlphabet.D | [EAlphabet.A, EAlphabet.A]
    | [EAlphabet.J, EAlphabet.B] | [EAlphabet.Z, EAlphabet.E]
    | [EAlphabet.A, EAlphabet.B, EAlphabet.C] | [EAlphabet.Z, EAlphabet.J, EAlphabet.E]

const t4: EAlphabetValues = EAlphabet.A
const t5: EAlphabetValues = EAlphabet.B // error
const t6: EAlphabetValues = [EAlphabet.A, EAlphabet.B, EAlphabet.C]

// (alternative type: all enum values permitted here, tuple can have 1,2 or 3 items)
type EAlphabetVarTuple = [EAlphabet, EAlphabet?, EAlphabet?]

// At last, we need a function to convert EAlphabet items back to a string again at run-time
declare function toString(t: EAlphabetValues): string
```

Choose, which of the types `EAlphabetStringLit`, `EAlphabetNarrow`, `EAlphabetBrand` and `EAlphabetValues` fits best, then you can use as property type in `foo` interface.

```
interface foo {
    bar: EAlphabetValues
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=71&ssc=54&pln=70&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAogggGwA4AsCGAjYAXKBvAWACgpSo4oBeKAcjhoBpiyoAhK21x5sgYQ5q9uJMgBEBo4SxgCYUsgDEBC+aQDiAtaqgAJATu0BJAYe0ApAWe0BpAde0AZAQ+0BZAa+0A5AV+0B5AX9tAAUBEO0ARQFI7QAlATjtAGUBZO0AFQEM7QBVAVztADUBIu0AdQFy7QANARrtAE0BRu0ALQE2mmIAX2JibABPJGBYRFRMHGTsACcASxAAcwc53Go6GigAH1oG7dpJfbp6I7MuI7a5I7hWIQuzOX6iUEgx5HQsbC80GZmAewA7vgeKQ4AwoDVwaJwXAwVAzuDLjDboiHr0ngBjP4gADOuAA1hx4O9Jl8fv8AQBtYkTT7fX6AgB0cAAulAAPTsqAAIjg3KeQxGbBmaBAABNgGLpvMlgAeLLAAAe2FAYpxUDxMsWAD4OFkAGT4KAAfWNGBF4tNAC4NYMIBg-ggoH0iMQAGZgEAY7BzbFQc2iiVS2YLRb+N3yqBKlXi9Wa0PagAUOJtGQAlDbWBag9LQ-LdYQRKQZjgwDMQBqoGh1VnA5Lc3KMtr0a6iILRjSPjha+KOD2cyG5RtdTt+-XB4tZTQGiPhXXg1qp5JZ2OF3njjRm0X9quG5OaGdNzvs+PFzRLkfRye10ObkIV9e91O2g9N5jsXioNgAIw2zuk-sOF5bkOS5YAGRmABuHk+SgEA-lwascTmRYQEwBBRmwP453FU882ArcsVxXBsAAJj-cYu2wQDqADXCbzDN1E2AtNQKgAE-hmfEcXBOigygJB5ggVY5gAN2AdUfkw4ZJXY1YUCrHEcXAn1sWIIjP2wABmCiSU+Gj-UfCdw2Yu9uVYzl2M47jwQQOZ8VGTA-nEp4FhVGY3TQDFRjdP5sMLFgMB+XTaRwIo0AQMAJJbAYZLeULsHCyKJKJSjSWZfZ-0+Rk6h2LKcEZcQdmpNLsrhfLsGZFkQX2Eq9IKsxwQqxlWDZYrmraJrSoKmBqu3drusq8rBparr6sq3g2qgOqEsZTr4qoxlGoW9LevfYivwAFhCqikqi9VqGauB1I-EiAFYdtJPaUsOkb2Es8D-hmE6NuwAA2S7Pmug7pqOsbZtYf7Fsmp5LIi9y0J9cSbQip0XmgUSIv2gTwOE7AVTFcFsDAJAMKgDFRSgdBxKgb8GFIqBOKgLSoFWYAIBxWKhQq8KZgyHG8eoGaqKB0kAH5ec+Pm+pezSAHZPrCn52dx0YueataiA0kiAA5JcS6WObl36RpgQWCoUPrla-ABOdXWZlzmdfGxk9ZW7KFH1yq1BFohLLgXAEGrbBwQBUYQGAWS0CgD0vVUissPx7FxJmXAKtplUGf9LzCUj4P4yWKtFjQBYq1wGZPQAWh9CBgGICUMS9ksQ89b1fQjv490TbBzaRiSMw1CcgA)